# FlexPaper in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, development, web-part, visual-studio

I'd like to create a custom web part with the [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/default.jsp) component so we can use it in SharePoint 2010. The user would go to the web part properties to select a SWF file (converted PDF) from the Site Assets and link to it, as well as set properties on the FlexPaper control. Any thoughts on how such a web part can be created?

I've got this code in a Content Editor Web Part, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
<script src="/helpdesk/SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/helpdesk/SiteAssets/js/flexpaper_flash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div style="position: relative; top: 10px; left: 10px">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fp = new FlexPaperViewer( 
       '/helpdesk/SiteAssets/js/FlexPaperViewer.swf',
       'viewerPlaceHolder', { config : {
       SwfFile : '/helpdesk/SiteAssets/js/wordman1.swf',
       Scale : 0.6, 
       ZoomTransition : 'easeOut',
       ZoomTime : 0.5,
       ZoomInterval : 0.2,
       FitPageOnLoad : true,
       FitWidthOnLoad : false,
       PrintEnabled : true,
       FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
       ProgressiveLoading : false,
       MinZoomSize : 0.2,
       MaxZoomSize : 5,
       SearchMatchAll : false,
       InitViewMode : 'TwoPage',

       ViewModeToolsVisible : true,
       ZoomToolsVisible : true,
       NavToolsVisible : true,
       CursorToolsVisible : true,
       SearchToolsVisible : true,

         localeChain: 'en_US'
       }});
</script>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Two things were wrong: Need to set file permissions to "Permissive" in Central Admin (as described here: http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/04/05/adding-flash-to-sharepoint-2010/). And the PDF file needs to be converted to SWF using the command line `C:\SWFTools\pdf2swf.exe Paper.pdf -o Paper.swf -T 9 -f`. Not crazy about the permissive file perms, but don't know a way around it.

Comment: Can you post this in an "answer" instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good description on how to do the stuff without "Permissive" mode at: http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/ 
Please note however, that it is about PDF w/o FlexPaper, so do changes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, SSpeedy. I wish the permissions were more fine-grained, such that we could set them per mime type rather than toggle all on/off. It's all-or-nothing currently.

Answer (score 1):

Use Page Viewer web part, i use an identical tools (FlippinBook) to generate swfs + index.html..upload the generated files from tools to your spesific document library, and set your Page Viewer web part URL property..another solution would be creating a custom pages with code-behind, e which will put in the page, an IFRAME with flash content tag pointing to SWF file url in the document library